# Question about the Definition of Smoothness at a Point

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, smooth-functions

Suppose $M$ and $N$ are smooth manifolds. Let $F:M \to N$ be any map. The definition of smoothness of $F$ is the following:

> **Def:** We say that $F$ is smooth if for each $p\in M$ there exist $(U,\phi)$ smooth chart for $M$ in $p$ and $(V,\psi)$ smooth chart for $N$ such that $F(U) \subseteq V$ and $\psi^{-1} \circ F \circ \phi:\phi(U)\to \psi(V)$ is smooth in $\phi(U)$ in the sense of Ordinary Calculus.

However, if I want to give a definition of *smoothness at a point*, I see at least two possible ways to do so:

Let $p\in M$.

> **Definition 1)** I say that **$F$ is smooth at $p$** if there exist $(U,\phi)$ smooth chart for $M$ in $p$ and $(V,\psi)$ smooth chart for $N$ such that $F(U) \subseteq V$ and $\psi^{-1} \circ F \circ \phi:\phi(U)\to \psi(V)$ is smooth in $\phi(U)$ in the sense of Ordinary Calculus.
>
> **Definition 2)** I say that **$F$ is smooth at $p$** if there exist $(U,\phi)$ smooth chart for $M$ in $p$ and $(V,\psi)$ smooth chart for $N$ such that $F(U) \subseteq V$ and $\psi^{-1} \circ F \circ \phi:\phi(U)\to \psi(V)$ is smooth in $\phi(p)$ in the sense of Ordinary Calculus.

**Are they equivalent? If not, which one is the correct?**

I noticed that:

**Pros of Definition 1)**

1) $F:M \to N$ is smooth (in M, according to the "Def" above) if and only if $F$ is smooth at $p$ for each $p$ in $M$.

**Cons of Definition 1)**

1) Smoothness of $F$ at $p$ implies smoothness of $F$ in an entire neihborhood of $p$ (which seems a too strong requirement)

2) In Ordinary Calculus the definition of smoothness at a point does not imply the smoothness in an entire neighborhoods of that point.

**Pros of Definition 2)**

1) It seems more similar to the definition of smoothness at a point given in Ordinary Calculus

**Cons of Definitions 2)**

1) I don't know if  $F:M \to N$ is smooth (in M, according to the "Def" above) if and only if $F$ is smooth at $p$ for each $p$ in $M$.

Comment: Can you try to look at what it says for the easiest manifold you can think of ? (e.g. $M=N=\mathbb{R}$

Comment: I was thinking if a map $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ which is smooth at a point $x_0$ is also smooth in a neighborhood of $x_0$ but I'm not able to give an answer. If the answer is not, then i think the correct definition of smoothness at a point for a manifold should be Definition 2)

Comment: Well imagine a map that is more and more differentiable, the closer you get to $0$; for instance it would be $C^1$ on $]-1,1[$, $C^2$ on $]-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}[$ but not at $\frac{1}{2}, -\frac{1}{2}$, $C^3$ as you get closed but not on the full interval and so on. Then it will be $C^\infty$ at $0$, but there is no neighbourhood of $0$ at which it is $C^\infty$.

Comment: Wonderful idea, even though now I have to think at a "concrete"example. But now, is it the case that a map $F:M \to N$ which is smooth at $p$ for each $p \in M$ (according to Definition 2) is also smooth in $M$ according to "Def"?

Because in Oardinary Clalculus we have that property!

Comment: Well you can try to prove that def 1) doesn't depend on the choice of the chart as long as it's small enough; and use that to prove it

Comment: Thank-you! :) I think I succeeded in proving that a map $F:M→N$ which is smooth at $p$ for each $p∈M$ (according to Definition 2) is also smooth in $M$ according to "Def". To be shure I will write the details in the post. So it only remains to give a concrete example of a map which is $C^\infty$ at a point but there is no neighborhood of that point in which it is also $C^\infty$. Can you give some hint?

Comment: I don't have a specific example in mind, but if you know how to construct a function $f$  that is bounded, $C^k$ on $]a-2\epsilon, b+2\epsilon[$, zero outside of $]a-\epsilon, b+\epsilon[$ such that $f^{(k)}$ is not $C^1$ at $a,b$, and $f$ is $C^\infty$ on $]a,b[$; then by summing these for well-chosen $a,b,\epsilon$'s and with sufficient coefficients to ensure convergence at each level, then you should be good

Comment: I will try but I think it's too much elaborate for me to construct it alone :( However, you have done great! Thank you very much!  :)